# Json server: Error: Insert failed, duplicate id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Hii all I am trying to post data to json server using post method , but unfortunately I have erros, my app have buttons follow, likes etc , I want when user clicks follow numbers increase and saved to the json file , so now when user clicks button I get the following error :

Note: am using fakes json server : [Fake Json server](https://itnext.io/using-json-server-to-create-a-restful-server-in-5-seconds-78b85ccf832b)

```
Error: Insert failed, duplicate id
    at Function.insert (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash-id\src\index.js:49:18)
    at C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4374:28
    at arrayReduce (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:683:21)
    at baseWrapperValue (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4373:14)
    at LodashWrapper.wrapperValue (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9052:14)
    at create (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\router\plural.js:221:52)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at next (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\jelly\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
POST /statuses 500 13.873 ms - -
```

Here is service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
import { Comment } from '../model/comments.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
   status: Status[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  statusUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/statuses';
  commentsUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/comments';

  getStatuses() {
    return this.http.get<Status[]>(this.statusUrl);
  }
  addStatus(status: Status) {
   return this.http.post(this.statusUrl, status);
  }
  addComments(comment: Comment) {
    return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, comment);
  }

}
```

here is ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
import { Comment } from '../model/comments.model';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 status: Status[];
 comment: Comment[];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.userService.getStatuses()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.status = data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.status);
      });

  }

  addComments() {
    this.userService.addComments(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.comment.push(this.addForm.value);
    });
  }
  followButtonClick(statusId) {
    const statusToUpdate = this.status.filter(status => status.id === statusId)[0];
    statusToUpdate.followers++;
    statusToUpdate.following++;
    this.persistStatus(statusToUpdate);
    }

    likesButtonClick(statusId) {
      const statusToUpdate = this.status.filter(status => status.id === statusId)[0];
      statusToUpdate.like++;
      this.persistStatus(statusToUpdate);
      }

  persistStatus(status) {
    this.userService.addStatus(status)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.status = status;
    });

  }
}
```

Here is json file :

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "statusId": 20,
      "likes": 121,
      "following": 723,
      "followers": 4433
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is model

```
export class Status {
    id: number;
    statusId: number;
    like: number;
    following: number;
    followers: number;
}
```

what am I doing wrong in my code ????

Comment: Looks like there's a unique key constraint on the Id field on the server side.

Comment: what do I need to change now?

Comment: What does your server side code look like? Does it generate unique ids for each Status posted to it? If not then, you need to provide a unique id value in your json while making the post call.

Comment: here is consolo.log status : `[{…}]0: followers: 4435following: 725id: 1likes: 121statusId: 20__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)  and remember am using fake json server
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) of the fake json-server you are using,:

> Id values are not mutable. Any id value in the body of your PUT or
>   PATCH request will be ignored. Only a value set in a POST request will
>   be respected, but only if not already taken.

You are trying to update an existing status, so you need a put call not post. Something like this:

```
updateStatus(status: Status) { 
    return this.http.put(this.statusUrl + '/' + status.id, status); 
}
```

And use it in the persistStatus function.

```
persistStatus(status) { 
    his.userService.updateStatus(status) 
    .subscribe(data => { 
        this.status = [status]; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to do that? am  strugling to get this work as I want, thanks

Comment: How are you creating status jsons that you send in post call? Are you reading them from a file?

Comment: yes from from json file  generated with json server

Comment: I don't understand. You are generating jsons from the json server and posting them back to the server? If yes, can you point me to the code where this is happening?

Comment: json sever creates a fake rest api and generate a fake file with name myJsonFile.json  inside there is sample data, inside this file u can add ur fake data , end point name etc, here is my repo https://github.com/throne1986/profile

Comment: @user9964622 It seems to me you are not trying to create a new status, but just want to update the  follower count on an existing status. Can you try using `PUT` call instead of post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182606/discussion-between-user9964622-and-curlybraces).